# Taking the derivative of a vector valued function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading *Special Relativity* by Nicholas Woodhouse and have trouble understanding the following argument: $\textbf B(\textbf r+\textbf v\tau,t+\tau)=\textbf B(\textbf r,t)$ where $\textbf B$ is a vector valued function. He then states that the derivative of $\textbf B$ with respect to $\tau$ at $\tau=0$ is $\textbf v\cdot grad \ \textbf B+\frac {\partial }{\partial t}\textbf B=0$. Could somebody explain to me why this is the case? How do you take the derivative of a vector valued function?

Comment: The expression is simply an application of the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$,

$$ \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} := \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\end{bmatrix}$$

Even when $x$ is scalar valued ($n=1$) this is still true, with the result just being the left-most column vector.

It seems like you have a function of two arguments which themselves depend on another variable $\tau$,
$$B(p, q)\ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \ p=r+v\tau\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ q=t+\tau$$

The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) lets us find,
$$ \frac{dB}{d\tau} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial \tau} $$

(I am assuming you understand [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)). Also remember that the product of a row-vector and a column-vector (with the row-vector on the left) is the same thing as a dot-product of the two as column-vectors. Hopefully that lets you figure out what's going on in your book.